# How do I have my program actually activate the quiz?

Tags: python

What is wrong with my coding. It is a simple conditional statement where you say yes or no to taking the quiz. If you type yes, you begin answering questions and if you type no, it just exits out of the function.

```
    play=input("\v Do you want to take the quiz or not? Yes or No? ").lower
    if play == "no":
        print("That's too bad")
        quit(main())  
    
        question_num=0
        green_point=0
        mean_point=0
        if play=="yes":
            print("Great! Let us Begin!")
            for questions,answers in QUESTIONS:
                playeranswer=input("{} " .format(questions))
```

But the program just ends once you type in an answer for play. I thought it was pretty clear what is supposed to happen. Why is it not doing anything?

Comment: Be careful that your `if play=='yes'` is inside the outer `if play=='no'`

Comment: indenting is messed up.

Comment: have a look at your indentation... remove the spaces before `if play=='yes'`

Comment: You're also missing the brackets for the `.lower()` method

Answer (score 1):

1- the indention is wrong with your coding

2- you forgot the `()` after `.lower`

your code should be like this :

```
play = input("\v Do you want to take the quiz or not? Yes or No? ").lower()
if play == "no":
    print("That's too bad")
    quit(main())

    question_num = 0
    green_point = 0
    mean_point = 0


elif play == "yes":
    print("Great! Let us Begin!")
    for questions, answers in QUESTIONS:
        playeranswer = input("{} " .format(questions))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not just the indentation. When you do this:

```py
play = input("\v Do you want to take the quiz or not? Yes or No? ").lower
```

It actually sets `play` to be the function `lower`, not the lowercase string that results from calling `lower()`. You need to add parentheses:

```py
play = input("\v Do you want to take the quiz or not? Yes or No? ").lower()
if play == "no":
    print("That's too bad")
    quit(main())

    question_num = 0
    green_point = 0
    mean_point = 0

elif play == "yes":
    print("Great! Let us Begin!")
    for questions, answers in QUESTIONS:
        playeranswer = input("{} " .format(questions))
```